# How can I get additional fields from Search API query?

Tags: 8, search

I have Search API DB backend where I will be retrieving thousands of results and I need some fields to get out of there as well, beside search item id, since doing additional query to MySQL with IN condition consisting of thousands of entries is nonsense.

Can't find any methods to do this in the code so far though.

I think the query option `search_api_retrieved_properties` is the key, but I was not able to make it work yet.

---

I have added the fields via `hook_search_api_db_query_alter` on tagged query but they are not present. Calling getField() on the result item always queries the source entity(= entity_load operation).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it looks like this is impossible.

Looking at `\Drupal\search_api_db\Plugin\search_api\backend\Database::search`:

```
  $result = $db_query->execute();

  foreach ($result as $row) {
    $item = $this->getFieldsHelper()->createItem($index, $row->item_id);
    $item->setScore($row->score / self::SCORE_MULTIPLIER);
    $results->addResultItem($item);
  }
```

The `$item` will receive only the item_id from the fetched row, so all added fields are lost :(